# Converting text to title case, except for certain words like 'the', 'a', 'of', etc.?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have commands scripts in my bashrc file, one that title cases a string, and another that creates a directory using the title cased string. The commands are:

```
tc() {
    sed 's/.*/\L&/; s/[a-z]*/\u&/g' <<<"$1"    
}

tcdir() {
    mkdir "$(tc "$1")";
}
```

How can I modify the tc() command so that it doesn't title case words like 'the', a', 'of', 'in', 'for', etc., unless of course they are the first word in the string? For example:

```
the name of the website is stackoverflow
```

gets transformed to

```
The Name Of The Website Is Stackoverflow
```

when ideally I would like it to get transformed to

```
The Name of the Website is Stackoverflow
```

Comment: pipe it to `sed -E 's/ (The|A|Of|I[sn]|For)\b/\L&/g'`... you need to manually specify all words...

Comment: @Sundeep Ok I tried piping it with sed -E 's/ (The|A|Of|I[sn]|For)\b/\L&/g' |  sed 's/.*/\L&/; s/[a-z]*/\u&/g' <<< "the name of the website is stackoverflow" but it outputs "The Name Of The Website Is Stackoverflow" and then hangs. It didn't fix the case on 'of', 'the' and 'is'. Is my method for piping it incorrect?

Comment: the order should be `echo "$1" | sed 's/.*/\L&/; s/[a-z]*/\u&/g' | sed -E 's/ (The|A|Of|I[sn]|For)\b/\L&/g'`

Comment: pure bash (no external programs called): http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/113666/29143 :)

Answer (score 0):

Pure `bash`, (add words to `case` as needed):

```
tc() { set ${*,,} ; set ${*^} ; c="$1 " ; shift 1 ;
       for f in ${*} ; do
           case $f in  A|The|Is|Of|For|And|Or|But|About) c+="${f,,} " ;;
                                                      *) c+="$f " ;;      
           esac ;
       done ; echo "$c"; }
```

Note: `shift 1` allows the first word to stay in title case.

Test:

```
tc the last of the mohicans
```

Output:

```
The Last of the Mohicans
```

Answer (score 0):

And another on the pure bash side:

```
tc()
{
  excluded_words=(a the if is of and for or but about)

  IFS='|'
  regex="^("${excluded_words[*]}")$"
  unset IFS  

  set ${*,,}

  out=${1^}

  shift

  for word
  do
    [[ "$word" =~ $regex ]] || word=${word^}

    out+=" $word"
  done

  echo "$out"
}
```

Nice thing here is you can add to the excluded_words array each of the words you don't want.  You could also populate the array using an external file